# (Pyton + HTML): Multiple interactive plotly charts to one HTML report

Tags: python, html, plotly

I created several chart in plotly and saved them as html file. Now, I need to create a report that includes these all charts and my own text (analysis on charts). The only way to create this report is HTML file ( as I want charts to be interactive).

Here is one sample of plotly charts that i created:

```
fig=go.Figure(go.Scatter(y=y, x=x, name='first sample',mode='lines'))
fig.write_html("first_sample.html")
```

How do I create an HTML report that consists of several charts (first_sample, second_sample, third_sample) + my analysis

I am new to HTML, that's why even though I found several helpful articles on the web, I was not able to apply it for my own case. Thank you in advace!